# How to link an external JS file correctly?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Post Lecture Task</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver">Mouse over me</h1>
    <script src="Documents/postlecture.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JS works if I include it internally but I am confused as to why it won't work when connected as an external js file.

```js
function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: What is the directory structure?

Comment: `src` must be accessible from your server. It's can't be outside your server public directory (as I understand you use it from `C:/Users/someName/Documents/postlecture.js`

Answer (score 0):

js src it will depend on where your file located .
also, in this example .i think you should replece

onmouseover="mouseOver"

with
onmouseover="mouseOver()"

Answer (score 0):

If your index.html file is at same location as the postlecture.js file, then you can do like following,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Post Lecture Task</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1 id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver()">Mouse over me</h1>
                    <script type="text/javascript"  src="postlecture.js"></script>
                </body>
        </html>


<!--postlecture.js file -->

    
    function mouseOver() {
      document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
    }
```